# Fedora 8 recently extreamly slow with frequent freeze ups

Tags: linux, fedora, performance

Over the last few weeks my Fedora 8 machine has been running extremely slow. Applications like Firefox constantly freeze up and I am seeing sustained spikes in CPU activity while carrying out typical tasks (browsing the web, compiling Java programs, running subversion operations etc). This all started happening suddenly, the machine was running fine for the past year and now it is frequently crawling.

I am looking for suggestions as to what may have happened to cause this. Maybe a list of possible explanations that I can look into?

Comment: Fedora 8 reached its end of life in January, 2009, which is over two and a half years ago. That means no more bug fixes — or security updates. You need to upgrade to a newer release. Fedora 15 is current. Since your problem happened suddenly, it's possible you have a hardware problem — or maybe you have suffered a security compromise.

Comment: @ mattdm I am using Fedora 8 for work reasons but they have recently switched everything to a new version of Ubuntu so I'm going to upgrade to that. I tried to reboot the computer but I got inconstant file system errors so I'm currently running a disk check. Its been going on since yesterday so will take a while. I think it is probably a hardware problem too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was inconsistencies in the file system caused by my hard drive failing. I realized what the problem was when I tried to reboot the computer, it couldn't start properly and then started to run fsck. fsck then reported that it had detected inconsistency errors in the file system.